# Digest error when chosing a value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the error as below, when i try to third time select a value from  dropdown:

> angular.js:9937 [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

The chosen value does not get updated in the dropdown.

Any idea how i can fix the error?

```
  <select id="country" ng-model="quoteRequest.quotationRequestItems[0].localSite.countryCode3"
                      ng-options="country.countryCode3 as country.countryName for country in countries"
                      ng-class="{dropdowWithLongData:isBrowserIE()}"
                      ng-change="changeCountryName(quoteRequest.quotationRequestItems[0].localSite); updateBillingInSameCountryBlock();detectChange('countryName');updateLocalContact(quoteRequest.quotationRequestItems[0].localSite.countryCode3)"
                      name="countryName"
                      required={{!nextClicked}>
                <option value=""></option>
              </select>
```

```
  $scope.changeCountryName = function (site) {
    console.log(site.countryCode3 +"COUNTRY CODE");
    site.countryName = $scope.countriesMap[site.countryCode3];
    console.log(site.countryName +"COUNTRY NAME");

  };
```

Comment: The `ng-change` directive calls four functions: `changeCountryName()`,`updateBillingInSameCountryBlock()`,`detectChange()`, and `updateLocalContact()`. One of those functions is likely the cause of the problem. Try removing each of them to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> ### Diagnosing This Error
>
> When you get this error it can be rather daunting to diagnose the cause of the issue. The best course of action is to investigate the stack trace from the error. You need to look for places where `$apply` or `$digest` have been called and find the context in which this occurred.
>
> There should be two calls:
>
> - The first call is the good `$apply`/`$digest` and would normally be triggered by some event near the top of the call stack.
> - The second call is the bad `$apply`/`$digest` and this is the one to investigate.
>
> Once you have identified this call you work your way up the stack to see what the problem is.
>
> - If the second call was made in your application code then you should look at why this code has been called from within an `$apply`/`$digest`. It may be a simple oversight or maybe it fits with the sync/async scenario described earlier.
> - If the second call was made inside an Angular directive then it is likely that it matches the second programmatic event trigger scenario described earlier. In this case you may need to look further up the tree to what triggered the event in the first place.

-- [AngularJS Error Reference - $rootScope - inprog](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest).

Answer (score 0):

check this condition before call excute the digest error.

```
if($scope.$$phase)
{
  site.countryName = $scope.countriesMap[site.countryCode3];
}
```